# mailjet API v3 reply-to not working

Tags: php, mailjet

I am using mailjet simple API v3 library to send emails. Here is the link:

https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple

Emails are sent successfully however reply to is not working.

Below are the 2 attempts that I tried:

```
$params = array(
    "method" => "POST",
    "from" => $from_email,
    "to" => $to_email,
    "subject" => $subject,
    "html" => $message_body,
    "Headers" => [
                   "Reply-To" => $reply_to_email
                  ]
);
```

And

```
$params = array(
    "method" => "POST",
    "from" => $from_email,
    "to" => $to_email,
    "subject" => $subject,
    "html" => $message_body,
    "Reply-To" => $reply_to_email
);
```

I do not have option to install composer so I have to use this simple API.

Comment: Does anyone know about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but there is no ability to set the Reply-To header as part of this version of the Mailjet API wrapper (Just like you can't set the From Name) for that you need to use latest version of the API wrapper at https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php

Comment: Same goes for the wrapper mentioned above. I always get a 400 error from the API when trying to set the Reply-To header. See: https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php/issues/183